# Duda contar desde un fichero .csv en python

Tags: python

Tengo este trozo de programa. Tengo que contar cuantas ciudades hay en cada estado, el cual introduce el usuario mediante un input. La cosa es que en el archivo que se llama *"cities.csv"*  todas las ciudades aparecen en el fichero como *"CA,Los Angeles,Mission Hills"* y hay más de 6000 datos (ciudades).

Necesito ayuda para resolver esto ya que no se como hacer para que cuando el usuario introduce *"California"* cuente dentro del archivo tanto las veces que aparece California como las veces que aparece CA. Claro, teniendo en cunta que hay unos 60 estados, y cada vez que el usuario introduce uno tiene que acortarse con su equivalente.

La información de las acortaciones está dentro del fichero *"states.csv"*, aparecen así: *"CA, California"*, etc.

```
def contarCiudades():

    estado = str(input("Introduce un estado: ")).capitalize()

    total = 0

    with open('cities.csv') as f:
        for linea in f:
            encontrado = linea.find(estado)
            if encontrado != -1 and encontrado != 0:
                total += 1
    with open('states.csv') as f:
        for linea in f:
            encontrado = linea.find(estado)
            if encontrado != -1 and encontrado != 0:
                total += 1

    if total== 0:
        print("No existe ese estado")    
    else:        
        print ("\nHay " + str(total) + " ciudades en " + str(estado))
```

El programa incluye muchas más cosas por lo que he tenido que acortarlo y subir solo este trozo, por eso está sin terminar y no es funcional. Tras haber estado mirando, creo que hay que utilizar un diccionario, pero aun no me han enseñado a programar con ellos.

Gracias por anticipado.

Comment: Me refiero a que hay dos ficheros .csv, uno de ellos relaciona el nombre del estado (California) con su acortación (CA), cuyo nombre es 'states.csv', y otro fichero diferente llamamdo 'cities.csv' que incluye 6000 ciudades las cuales están como 'CA,Los Angeles,Mission Hills'. Por tanto, como el usuario introduce el nombre del estado completo, primero hay que relacionar dicho estado, si existe con su acortamiento y posteriormente contar las veces que aparece el acortamiento en el fichero 'cities.csv'. Te añado un par de líneas en el siguiente comentario.

Comment: En el fichero states.csv (aparecen en un excel, pero el fichero es .csv): AP,Armed Forces Pacific 
AR,Arkansas 
AS,American Samoa 
AZ,Arizona 
CA,California
 CO,Colorado
 CT,Connecticut
 DC,Washington DC
 DE,Delaware

Comment: AK,Yukon Koyukuk,Tanana
 AK,Yukon Koyukuk,Venetie
 AL,Autauga,Autaugaville
 AL,Autauga,Billingsley
 AL,Autauga,Booth
 AL,Autauga,Jones

Comment: Esto es el fichero cities.csv, si pudiera mandarte una captura del archivo o el archivo sería más fácil de entender, pero en resumen, son ficheros .csv, que al abrirlos abre una especie de hoja de excel, en la que hay 1 dato por línea (Digamos): linea 1:AP,Armed Forces Pacific, linea 2: AR,Arkansas, linea 3. AS,American Samoa y asi sucesivamente, y lo mismo para el otro fichero

Comment: Lo siento no se a que te refieres... No, los csv no tienen cabecera, desde la linea 1 son datos.

Comment: Desde la línea uno lineas de datos, sin cabeceras

Comment: He creado una respuesta, si no es exactamente lo que necesitas, tienes algún problema o no he entendido algo, no dudes en comentar,

Comment: Sii, es perfecto, no se por donde agradecerte :)

Comment: De nada, para ser sincero me ha costado más comprender la estructura de los datos que el problema en si, y mira que en tu código se veía claramente que abrías dos archivos, pero ayer ni me di cuenta,  XD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el ejemplo voy a partir de dos csv como los siguientes:

**`states.csv`**

```
AK,Alaska
AL,Alabama
```

**`cities.csv`**

```
AK,Yukon Koyukuk,Tanana
AK,Yukon Koyukuk,Venetie
AL,Autauga,Autaugaville
AL,Autauga,Billingsley
AL,Autauga,Booth
AL,Autauga,Jones
```

La idea seria primero iterar sobre las lineas de `states.csv` para obtener si existe, el nombre acortado para el estado ingresado.

Si existe, procedemos a iterar sobre `cities.csv` al completo, comprobando si la primera columna coincide con el nombre acortado previamente encontrado.

Por norma general, es mejor usar el módulo `csv` de la biblioteca estándar para parsear archivos de éste tipo, es más simple y más seguro (por ejemplo lidia con los acotados por nosotros).

```
import csv


def contar_ciudades():
    estado = str(input("Introduce un estado: ")).capitalize()
    
    # Buscamos el nombre acortado del estado, si existe
    with open('states.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for short_name, state in reader:
            if state == estado:
                break
        else:
            print("No existe ese estado")
            return
    # Buscamos en cities.csv todas las lineas con el nombre acortado
    with open('cities.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')    
        total = sum(state == short_name for state, *_ in reader)      
        print(f"\nHay {total} ciudades en {estado}")
```

> ```
> >>> contar_ciudades()
> Introduce un estado: Alabama
>
> Hay 4 ciudades en Alabama
>
> >>> contar_ciudades()
> Introduce un estado: alaska
>
> Hay 2 ciudades en Alaska
>
> >>> contar_ciudades()
> Introduce un estado: Ontario
>
> No existe ese estado
> ```

Si sabemos seguro que el archivo `cities.csv` está ordenado alfabéticamente en función de la primera columna (o al menos todas las ciudades de un estado están contiguas), es podriamos planternos dejar de iterar en cuanto detectemos que el bloque de ese estado  ha terminado:

```
import csv 


def contar_ciudades():
    estado = str(input("Introduce un estado: ")).capitalize()
    
    # Buscamos el nombre acortado del estado, si existe
    with open('states.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for short_name, state in reader:
            if state == estado:
                break
        else:
            print("No existe ese estado")
            return
    # Buscamos en cities.csv todas las lineas con el nombre acortado
    with open('cities.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        total = 0
        search = False
        for state, *_ in reader:
            if state == short_name:
                total += 1
                search = True
            else:
                if search:
                    break 
        print(f"\nHay {total} ciudades en {estado}")
```